# Trouble allocating heap memory

Tags: c, memory

Background: I am trying to open a file that I altered and reserve enough heap memory for all its' contents. However, I am struggling to find a solution to the program ending before all the file's contents are read into heap memory.

Best Guess: I do not think I have reserved enough bytes in heap memory || I have cast my pointer as the wrong type (currently it is type char), which may have adversely affected the way in which and how much of my heap memory was reserved.

```
FILE *fptr3;

void highgest_and_lowest_Jan123(void)
{
int c;
unsigned int i = 0;
char *file;
long int size = 0;


fptr3 = fopen("/Users/sam/Desktop/Altered_AL_Weather_Station.txt", "r+");
if (fptr3 == 0)
{
    printf("There was an error creating the file.\n");
    exit(0);
}

fseek(fptr3, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fptr3);
file = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
if(!file)
{
    puts("Not enough memory");
    exit(1);
}

fseek(fptr3, 0, SEEK_SET);

do
{
    c = fgetc(fptr3);
    if ((int)c == EOF)
        break;
    file[i] = c;
    printf("%c", file[i]);
    i++;
} while((int)c != EOF);

// pus memory back on the heap
free(file);

}
```

Here is what my current output is: 
[image]

But, here is what my output SHOULD BE: 
[image]

Comment: What happens when you debug through the program? Where does it fail?

Comment: Use `int c;` instead of `char c;` The return value of `fgetc` is an `int`.

Comment: Why are you casting `c`? `fgetc` returns an `int`, declare `c`  as `int`

Comment: @user3386109 I am using unix.

Comment: @RSahu I implemented the changes you suggested, yet my output remained the same.

Comment: @Liftalots, If you can, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help.

Comment: The while condition should terminate on `i < size`. Try outputting `size` and comparing it to how much output you are getting.

Comment: @Liftalots I took another look, but I don't see anything that would cause the problem that you're describing. At least not in the code that's been posted.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` is expanding to a value of `-1` on most systems. `fgetc` is returning `int`. But you are reading it into a `char` variable. Now assume that your file is containing a value of `0xFF`. In this case the byte value of `c` would be `0xFF`, which, when cast to `int` will become `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is a representation for `int` `-1` value.  Then it is compared to `EOF`, and the comparison returns true, effectively stopping your loop. Solution: Declare `c` as `int`.